# "Display: Inline" No me funciona

Tags: html, css, navbar, display

soy bastante novato en programacion, estoy empezando con la html y la ul para hacer una navbar no me funciona en inline.

El HTML:

```
<div>
  <ul id=navbarlist>
<li> <a href="index.html">Home</a> </li>
<li> <a href="about.html">About</a> </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

El CSS:

```
#navbarlist{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
display: inline;
}
```

No se que estoy haciendo mal o que me falla, a ver si me podeis echar un cable.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu selector CSS esta apuntando directamente al contenedor de lista desordenada, entonces la propiedad y valor: **`display: inline`** lo va a afectar a el pero no así a los elementos internos.

La forma mas simple, es que tengas una estructura de clases aplicadas a todas las etiquetas para que el CSS declarado se aplique sobre el elemento o elementos deseados así:

```html
    <style>
    .navbarlist{
      font-family: 'Open Sans', helvetica, sans-serif;
      color: white;
    
    }
    .navbarlist__elemento {
        display: inline;
    }
    </style>
    <div>
      <ul class=navbarlist>
        <li class="navbarlist__elemento">
          <a class="navbarlist__elemento-enlace" href="index.html">
            Home
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbarlist__elemento">
          <a class="navbarlist__elemento-enlace" href="about.html">
            About
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Estas observaciones, por que lo que tratas de hacer es pasar [los `li` de una naturaleza de bloque a *inline*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) dado eso tu selector debe hacer plena referencia a estos elementos

De esta forma que te propongo te va a ser mas simple construir tus selectores e identificando a cual o cuales etiquetas deseas afectar con esas propiedades y valores.

**Lectura relevante**

- [Selectores CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_CSS)

Comment: Muchas gracias, solucionado. Tendre en cuenta lo de las clases y los elementos individuales para proximos errores.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que sucede es que estas apuntando al elemento ul, mas no a los elementos li que están contenidos dentro del ul, la solución seria la siguiente.

```css
#navbarlist > li {
  display: inline
}
```

```html
<ul id=navbarlist>
<li> <a href="index.html">Home</a> </li>
<li> <a href="about.html">About</a> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, solucionado!!